# Zend Studio on Eclipse "HELIOS"

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, eclipse-3.6

I'm trying to install Zend Studio on an existing installation of Eclipse HELIOS, but Zend doesn't want to behave. The [PDF instructions here](http://www.zend.com/topics/Installing-Studio-v7x-Plugins.pdf) say it's for "Eclipse Galileo version 3.5.1 only". Sure enough, I'm getting a strange error on a Helios.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
```

I've already upgraded to Helios and don't want to go back to Galileo, so has anyone solved this problem or knows how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio 7.x does not support Helios.  Studio 8.x which is just about to go to beta does.

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux (Ubuntu) I was able to install multiple versions of Eclipse for various purposes. You can install a new Eclipse Galileo version 3.5.1 and it should not effect your Helios.

For a good explanation of how to do this see: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18678.html